# BigQuery golang client: which context to use?

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I'm using the Go BigQuery client package and I'm a bit confused about `context` usage.

In the docs, only the `Put` function explicitly mentions to use a new context with timeout to avoid indefinite retries. Is it safe to use `context.Background()` for all other calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [golang site](https://golang.org/pkg/context/):

> Package context defines the Context type, which carries deadlines,
>   cancellation signals, and other request-scoped values across API
>   boundaries and between processes.

Context, then, are designed to be adjusted and customized for each use case. You would use the functions provided by the library to achieve that.

> The WithCancel, WithDeadline, and WithTimeout functions take a Context
>   (the parent) and return a derived Context (the child) and a
>   CancelFunc. Calling the CancelFunc cancels the child and its children,
>   removes the parent's reference to the child, and stops any associated
>   timer

Thus, the [goDocs](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Inserter.Put) recommends the use of WithTimeout function in your context while inserting data to BigQuery and preventing from duplicates, as you have already seen.

The only must is to pass a non-nil Context. You would usually use `context.Background()` as a way to go (as I can see in [snippets.go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/bigquery/snippets/snippet.go) shared from Cloud Github), yet you are safe to pass `context.TODO` if you are unsure about which one to use.